# Fetching argument of function from cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, arguments

I have this function to wrap a specific number of divs into a row.

```
function rowCreation(a) {
    a = $.cookie("col-layout");
    if(typeof(a)==="undefined") a = 3;

    if ($("div.gallery-item").parent().is("div.row")) {
        $('div.row').replaceWith(function () {
            return $('div.gallery-item', this);
        });
    }
    var divs = $("section#gallery-wrapper div.gallery-item");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += a) {
        divs.slice(i, i + a).wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");
    }
}
```

But something seems to go wrong and I can't figure out what exactly. The first row is formed corretly, it contains `a` elements. But all the remaining divs are put into one single row, even when there are more than `a` of them!

Comment: can u make a fiddle for this at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: No, because in my experience cookies don't work on jsfiddle. I will try a test case though

Comment: try jsbin.com then :)

Surely they work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the first line :

```
a = $.cookie("col-layout");
```

Your function `rowCreation` treats `a` as a number, but the cookie is giving it out like a string. So, when you do this,

```
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += a) {
    divs.slice(i, i + a).wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");
}
```

> When i = 0,

You're asking the array to be sliced between 1 and "05" (concat i + "a"), thats fine, because these exist. So no problems.

> When i = 5,

You're asking the array to be sliced between 5 and "15" (concat i + "a"), so this takes off all the arrays and wraps it in one `.row`. That's why its problematic for you.

Try parsing the cookie retrieved `"col-layout"` to a variable of type `Number`, like this :

```
a = parseInt($.cookie("col-layout"), 10);
```

[More info about `parseInt` here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Silly mistake. Thanks a lot!